# Cannot open dataset in designer view?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I can open the project, build it, run it, etc. and that all works fine. However, I cannot open a dataset in the designer view. when I choose view in designer, it opens a XML Schema Explorer window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within VS2015, right click on your .xsd in the Solution Explorer, choose "Open With" and then choose the appropriate editor. Not sure what happened, but maybe the default viewer for that particular DataSet got changed